# How to route traffic from ethernet to a tun device (create a VPNed ethernet port)

Tags: networking, network-interface, openvpn, vpn, route

I have a **N**etwork **V**ideo **R**ecorder which is connected to a raspberry pi directly through ethernet, and the raspberry pi is connected to internet through `wlan0`. I want to route all the traffic from the NVR through a VPN connection on the raspberry pi.

Here's how I'm starting the VPN:

```
openvpn --config /home/pi/my_conf.conf --pull-filter ignore redirect-gateway --route-noexec
```

I'm ignoring the routes pushed by the server through these commands that [I found on the open VPN tutorials](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/IgnoreRedirectGateway). Upon inspection, I see that a `tun0` device is created after I connect to my VPN.

So in order to route the traffic from the NVR to the VPN, I need to give the `eth0` interface of the raspberry pi a static IP in the range used by the NVR. I did it by the following in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
interface eth0

static ip_address=192.168.1.1/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1
```

My raspberry `wlan0` has the gateway `192.168.0.1` so there's no conflict. Now that I have an IP address for the eth interface which is in the range of the NVR, and I have a connection to the VPN server on the `tun0`, all I need to do is to add a route to `tun0` for the IP addresses the NVR is going to access. Since I want to access some IP cameras in the range 192.168.0/24, here's what I did to my routing table:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    304    0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     304    0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
192.168.255.5   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
```

you can see that everything in the range `192.168.1.0/24` goes through `tun0` because it has metric `0`.

Even though I'm also running `dnsmasq` on `eth0`, I'm using a static IP address on the NVR too, which is `192.168.1.9`.

Obviously I can't access any cameras in the NVR. I tried to add connection on the NVR to the `192.168.1.189` camera. I tried to run `tcpdump` on `eth0`, this is mainly what I see:

```
17:10:46.673062 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.1.189 tell 192.168.1.9, length 46
```

The NVR (`192.168.1.9`) is trying to find out who is `192.168.1.189`, but there's no response. Nothing is being routed, I guess. I also tried to ping `192.168.1.189` on raspberry pi just to see if it worked. It worked the first time I tried. After some minutes, I can't ping it anymore, I don't know why. Pinging `192.168.1.1` always works though.

**UPDATE:**

I kinda understood the problem I'm having. Since the NVR is on the `192.168.1.0/24` subnet and is trying to access a camera on the same subnet, its IP packets are not sent to the gateway (raspberry pi). It instead tries to find where is `192.168.1.189` (the camera) by sending ARP requests as I was seeing in the tcpdump.

In order to solve this problem I changed the subnet of the NVR to `192.168.2.0/24` and gave the address `192.168.2.1` to the `eth0` interface of the raspberry pi. I now can see every packet sent by the NVR to the cameras and to some amazon servers and so. However, there is no response. The NVR only sends packets but receives nothing. I've checked and the routes to `tun0` are ok so the packets should go through it. However packets are not returning.

**UPDATE:**

instead of manually adding routes, I added the following to my open vpn configuration file in the client:

```
route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
route-metric 0
route-nopull
```

right below `client`. I can now see this route on the routing table after I connect my VPN. I can also ping to it from the raspberry pi and it works. However it looks like the NVR still only sends packets, and receives nothing

**Important:** If I run `tcpdump -vvv -i eth0` I see a lot of packets destined to `192.168.1.189` which is my camera. They should go to `tun0` because there's a route with metric `0` that makes them go through it. If I run `tcpdump -vvv -i tun0` I see nothing, even if I let it for minutes. So things are not being routed through there. If, however, I run `ping 192.168.1.189` inside my raspberry pi (through ssh) I can see all the ping packets in tcpdump of `tun0`, which confirms that the route works. It isn't working for the packets coming from ethernet though.